# Does Accept-Ranges work with RequestBuilder in GWT?

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, http-headers

I am trying to use RequestBuilder in GWT to see if Accept-Ranges is supported.
Following is my client code:

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,pathToServlet);
builder.setHeader("Range","bytes=0-10");
RequestCallback callback = new RequestCallback() {

@Override
public void onError(Request arg0, Throwable arg1) {
}

@Override
public void onResponseReceived(Request req, Response res) {
    log.info("Text:"+res.getText());
    log.info("Code:"+res.getStatusCode());
}
};

try {
  builder.sendRequest(null, callback);
} catch (RequestException e) {}
```

And my servlet code is just a simple test code:

```
public class RangeTest extends HttpServlet{

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RangeTest.class);

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String output = new String("This is a test string to be sent to the client");
    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(output);
}
}
```

In the output I get on the client, following is printed:

```
Text:This is a test string to be sent to the client
Code:200
```

What I expected was, since I gave the range header as 0-10 in the request, only the first 10 bytes will be sent to the client. But here the entire string is getting sent. What am I doing wrong here? Is there anything I have missed?

Comment: You are correct. I read through DefaultServlet source code and saw that I have to evaluate it myself. But then what's the purpose of providing such a header if it is not handled automatically and I have to write the code to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel my comment is more readable for other as answer (and effectively it is one):

You are not evaluating the range-header in your servlet-method. And the super class `HttpServlet` does not evaluate it either (but `DefaultServlet` from Tomcat).

The servlet specification has left most of the implementation work to providers like Apache. This explains why API classes like `HttpServlet` does not do the work of interpreting special http headers, but provider classes like the mentioned Tomcat-DefaultServlet. The main purpose of a specification is mainly to enable different implementations not to force people to only one.